# Using git for a project with 2 lines of development

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fork

I work for a company that does plugin development. We typically maintain our plugins for the 2 most recent major versions of the parent application. Major releases of the parent application's plugin API are usually mostly backwards compatible, but there are always some obsoleted/deprecated pieces along with several new APIs. As such, we usually have 2 lines of development that diverge over time. At first the divergences are small as we start by fixing all the obsolete calls. Over time the divergences can become large as we start to use the new APIs.  Merging between these branches can be a pain as you have to make sure you aren't merging code that uses parts of the API that aren't available in the other version.

I need some help in determining the best workflow for this situation. I will lay out some of my ideas below. The parent application releases new major versions on a yearly basis. As such, let's assume a plugin API for 2013 and 2014.

#### 1. Maintaining a branch for each version of the API

We have 2 long-running centralized branches, 1 for each version of the API (e.g. develop_2013, develop_2014). We develop against develop_2013 and consistently merge to develop_2014. Being that the API is *mostly* backwards compatible, this usually works fine. Any development against new pieces of the API is done in develop_2014 and is not merged back.

I'm cautious of this method being that git is not really geared towards maintaining long-running divergent branches.

#### 2. Fork for each version of the API

We now have a situation where we have a repository for each major version of the parent application (e.g. plugin_2013 and plugin_2014). We now must merge code between each repository through merge requests or by adding one as a remote to the other. We could perhaps cherry pick changes.

I'm cautious of this method because it introduces more overhead into the process.

If possible I would prefer to keep all development for a particular plugin contained within 1 repository. I am just concerned about the hassle of having 2 branches that will get more and more divergent over time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you say "git is not really geared towards maintaining long-running divergent branches."? Github uses the ability to have completely unrelated branches in the same repository to drive github pages (gh-pages).

Comment: Are you tagging releases off of both API branches? If you are, and you're in a single repository, when the 2015 API comes out, you could just delete the 2013 branch (last tag would make sure that history is still reachable) and then create the 2015 branch off of the 2014 branch. How important is it to keep the history of deprecated API branches?

Comment: @Charlie It seems to me like the git branching model intends that each line of development is eventually destined to converge back into a single line of development. In my case my 2 branches will only diverge more over time. If I were to discard specific changes during a merge, would git know that for future merges? or would I have to always reject those changes every time I did a merge?

Comment: @Charlie That is the intention. I would prefer to tag a final 2013 release and remove the branch. I would then branch for 2015 off of 2014 and make the necessary updates for obsoleted API calls.

We have been experimenting with using git flow, but I'm not sure how that really works when we now have to maintain 2 active lines of development.

Comment: Then do it :) Git flow and all other branching models really don't mean squat unless you have a team that agrees to follow them. And there's no reason you can't define a model that fits the needs of your projects, so long as it's technically feasible, and git is very flexible, with all kinds of tools and tricks like [`rerere`](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html) and many others.

Comment: Ahh...I have not heard of `rerere`! I think that solves what I was most concerned about. I did not want to have to deal with re-resolving the same conflicts every time we merge between the 2 branches. We currently use Perforce so 2013 and 2014 are essentially separate repos in git terms. I would have to do 1 merge and do the initial resolve of all the current conflicts. After that `rerere` should remember. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my original posting of this I've realized was due to my lack of experience with git.  Maintaining 2 long-running branches in the same repo works fine for us.  The real underlying concern that I didn't quite understand at the time I posted the question was that I didn't want to have to resolve the same merge conflicts every time I merged.  I wasn't sure if git handled it out of the box, but rerere certainly would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a release branch and a hotfix branch, maybe you already know git flow https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow. 
For me it is the best way to keep the code under control. 
In other hand, in your case I use to isolate api related calls to avoid api changes to impact too much in the development.